# Does Rally's Fetch API support recursive fetching?

Tags: rally

I am trying to build a tree view of our UserStory hierarchy in an excel document. Right now, I am recursively going through Jason objects attempting to get the children for each user story, and continuing until the child count is 0.

But, I am getting nowhere after getting the initial children. For each one of those children, some should have children as well.

**Is there some way Rally allows this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WSAPI used to support this but it was terribly inefficient for deeply nested hierarchies.  It is limited to one level currently.  You'll have to recursively look up the children at each level of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Epic Progress app in the app catalog for an example of how placeholders can be used to traverse a tree.